# Conditional code elements or variables in jquery

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

I have a variable that I would like to not affect condition or donot charge when necessary, ie when not in this case the DIV # sidebar

My code is:

```
var top = $('#sidebar').offset().top - parseFloat($('#sidebar').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
var _height = $('#sidebar').height();
var _original_top = $('#sidebar').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    var z = $('footer').offset().top;
    if (y >= top && (y + _height) < z) {
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('stuck-bottom').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        if ((y + _height) > z) {
            $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed').addClass('stuck-bottom');
        }
        else $('#sidebar').removeClass('stuck-bottom').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

If I put this code does not work: (

```
if ($('#sidebar')) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is that your `if` always executes the code, you need to change how you detect if `#sidebar` exists. This may be because `$('#sidebar')` will usually evaluate to true, even if there are no matching elements, because `$()` returns a valid jQuery object. To have the condition only succeed when `#sidebar` actually exists, try:

```
if ($('#sidebar').length) { ... }
```

However, if your problem is that the condition never succeeds even if `#sidebar` exists, your code may be getting executed before the DOM has loaded. You'll need to wrap your code in a `$.ready()` function, so it doesn't execute until the page has been downloaded, parsed and rendered:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    if ($('#sidebar').length) { ... }
});
```

Comment: And as you would to condition multiple items? ... if ($('#gallery ul') || $('#platos ul') || $('#live ul')) {.. }

Comment: again, check the length property to be sure you're getting the results you expect: if ($('#gallery ul').length || $('#platos ul').length || $('#live ul').length) { ... }